# Tabs under navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls

I'm quite new to iOS development and recently I saw several apps have nice tabs under navigation bar. Take the glassdoor app as an example, how are the new and all tabs in the image below implemented? I wasn't able to find anything like this in xcode object library. Is it a customized segmented control?

[image: tabs under navigation bar]

Edit: Thanks to the suggestion of using [Cocoa control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com). [This open source project](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagingmenucontroller) seems to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: This stuff may help you
https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl .. but its in objective C. but you will get ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find a lot of custom controls just search with segmented

https://www.cocoacontrols.com

Comment: Thanks. This one solved it for me. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagingmenucontroller

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have two options, either you use a segmented control/tab controller or you can implement a third party class to handle the tabs, third party classes generally subclass UITabBarController or segmented control. I have used this simple class to create tabs https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController; I also found this one https://github.com/dkhamsing/DKScrollingTabController. Is really easy to find this kind of controls on github or cocoacontrols